# how to run activemq using ant

Tags: java, ant, jms, activemq-classic

I am new to Apache Activemq.I am using apache-activemq-5.1.0. I need
to run Activemq using ant.How should i do this.Any help is greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions given in the [ActiveMQ Examples](http://activemq.apache.org/examples.html)?  It looks like ant tasks are used to run the examples.  The exanple ant build file(s) should give you information on how to do this.